# 6/2 to 6/3 Junction box to extend wire

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a 6/2 (two hot one neutral) from panel and need to move the stove about 4 feet. Electrician told me to get a 6/3 wire to convert it and add the extra length I need. But he also told me to connect the 6/2 neutral to the 6/3 white neutral and had me get a ground screw and caps. My question is why do I need caps and a ground screw? Shouldn't I be connecting both 6/2 hots to the 6/3 black and red and the 6/2 neutral to the white as he said, but then what do I use the cap for? If I ground the  6/3 ground wire (one end) to jbox screw and other end to stove ground screw what would the cap be for? Or did he mean to either cap off the 6/3 ground (both ends), or, ground the 6/3 ground to the stove and to the jbox. [image][image][image]

Comment: Is the previous run in metal conduit? If not, is the previous box grounded in some fashion?

Comment: No metal conduit that I can see near the run of the cable. There may be one closer to the panel but not sure if the cable is in there or not.

Comment: I can’t follow the wire properly due to garage walls and other walls in the way of the entire run.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the existing stove junction box please?

Comment: 6/2 doesn't have a neutral, it has a ground - which you're not allowed to use as a neutral ...

Comment: There is no existing junction box. I was going to add one to extend the wire. I thought the third bare wire of the 6/2 was ground too but electrician insisted it was neutral, I then read later that it is called a concentric neutral or shared ground/neutral. (Or so I think)

Comment: My 6/2 goes from panel to plug outlet and stove plugs into that outlet currently.

Comment: Does this "6/2" as you call it have a WHITE neutral wire or a BARE neutral and a white hot?  When you say "electrician" do you mean "Home Depot stockboy"?

Comment: Lol no it was an electrician I consulted with and thought I was good to go but then questioned it a bit afterward. The 6/2 has a black and black with red stripe and then a bare.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the exposed wire end then please?

Comment: Thank you, I’ve added a photo of the wire coming from the panel. He had me buy a 6/3 that now contains a black, red, white, and ground. Told me to connect the bare wire to the new white wire, black to black, black/red to red, and had me buy ground screws and caps. What do I do with the new bare wire/ground? Also added second picture of the 6/3 with bare ground bought for the extension.

Comment: @Jbandjb is throwing a ~$500 widget at the issue in the cards? Also, what are you planning to put where the range once lived?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by widget? I want to move the range onto other wall, so nothing will be where range is now. All I’m trying to do is extend the wire g about 4 feet to move it.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Does that look like SE cable to you?  I can't tell if the aluminum bare wire is a mesh that's been twisted together, or just another wire.

Comment: Could you label these pictures to indicate what they are/where they are located?  Did you buy aluminum wire on purpose? Does the stove need 40A or 50A? Also will you be able to make this splice in a junction box, that will remain accessible without using tools?

Comment: @Jbandjb "widget" is just a way of saying "device" -- I have an idea for how to solve your conundrum safely, but I'm not sure if it's in the cards for you from a budgetary standpoint.  Also, can you post photos of any labeling on the existing cable, please?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica -- it's *some* flavor of SE cable, I can tell you that much, I'm not sure if it's SEU as we know it today or some other form of SE though

Comment: I don’t think that would be in the budget honestly. The picture of the two black and bare ground/neutral is what went into my three prong stove outlet directly from the panel, no junction box. The second and third are the same thing-it uploaded twice. That one is 6/3 SE aluminum and yes the idea was al to al connection. I was planning on adding a junction box splicing original wire with new wire extension and was going to put it under the floor in the joists in the basement-unfinished ceiling

Comment: and then run The 6/3 directly to stove to hardwire it removing the ground strap and hooking up the black/red/white and ground. I am having a hard time with the junction box wiring based on what I was told. My plan is to put the black m(existing wire) with black (new wire), black red stripe (existing wire) with red (new wire) and bare neutral (or ground) (existing wire) to both the neutral and white (new wire). I could run a pigtail ground to green screw in junction if necessary.

Comment: The other electrician as I said had me buy caps and ground screws which then when I went to do it had me a bit confused. He told me to connect the bare wire (existing) to white (new) but then had me questioning do he intend to have me cap off the new wire ground and if so, both ends?

Answer (score 0):

If you can do this depends on several things is the 3rd wire separately insulated and if the AHJ will allow it. If so you would also need to add a ground going back on a circuit from or to the same panel.

If the 3rd wire is not separately insulated you would need to live in a state that allows minor modifications (extensions less than 5’ can use the code when built. table 1E in Oregon NOT ALL states have this exemption).
You could not use 4 wire unless the 3rd wire was insulated and the AHJ will allow remarking and you add the grounding or green.